# Is there any kind of template engine in VB?

Tags: templates, vba

Is there any kind of template engine in VB? Something akin to Apache velocity or Freemarker?

My goal is to be able to dynamically generate sql statement criteria for an MS Access application based on form input, with something more powerful than string cats.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? Even those who are not familiar with these particular template engines may still be able to help you if you explain what you need. Also, VB6, or VB.NET.

Comment: The platform is MS-Access 2003, and the goal is arbitrary text generation such as emails, notification messages, complex meta-data driven dynamic sql queries... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [MiniTemplator](http://www.source-code.biz/MiniTemplator/). 
MiniTemplator is a compact template engine for HTML files, available in Java, PHP and Visual Basic (VB/VBA). It can also be used for non-HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

[T4 templates for VB.NET.](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/T4TemplatesVisualStudioCodeGenerationScreencast.aspx)

Comment: This seems to be used only for code generation for Visual studio. I want to generate arbitrary text.

Comment: Can T4 templates generate arbitrary text or are they just for code generation plugins to Visual studio as the MSDN docs imply?

Comment: If you're talking post compilation (during runtime) probably not.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) on a project once.  It has C# port which you should be able to use from VB as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Format()](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-format-function-custom-string-formats) function.

Comment: An example would be useful. I see nothing useful for this question in that function